# Live stream prerecorded footage to YouTube using FFMPEG

Tags: batch-file

So, I recorded a video of me playing a game using FRAPS, and I was wondering how to live stream it to YouTube using FFmpeg in batch. I want to live stream in 1080p at 60fps in high quality, and my internet connection speed is 1Gbps. My OS is Windows 10 Creators Home. How can I do this without having the video sped up or slowed down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -re -i mxgtavls.mp4 -r 60 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5120k -c:a aac^
                                         -b:a 256k -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -threads 0 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -y -f flv^
                                         "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/"(stream key)
```